# Creating a table with one column as the rows and the other as the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with week end dates, user ids and an assigned score per week. I want to create a new table with the week end dates as columns and the user ids as rows. It would then match the user ID from the row with the week end date in the column and pull in the correct score. I am able to create the dataframe but can't match in the correct column, any help on this would be really appreciated

It should look something like this:

```
      01/01/2020   07/01/2020   14/01/2020    21/01/2020          
1     0.8          0.8          0.95          0.66       
2     0.9          0.6          0.55          0.56    
3     1.0          0.4          0.66          0.9
4     0.5          0.2          0.77          0.8
```

This is the data:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'week_end_date': {1: '2020-09-25',
  662: '2020-08-14',
  1719: '2020-10-16',
  5780: '2020-09-11',
  8589: '2020-09-18',
  14569: '2020-10-09',
  15334: '2020-10-30',
  19864: '2020-10-02',
  21641: '2020-11-06',
  24117: '2020-09-25',
  33090: '2020-10-02',
  38253: '2020-09-04',
  44078: '2020-09-11',
  53185: '2020-09-18',
  56337: '2020-10-09',
  59212: '2020-10-23',
  63782: '2020-11-13',
  64287: '2020-10-16',
  65208: '2020-11-13',
  65483: '2020-10-23',
  66264: '2020-09-25',
  70286: '2020-09-11',
  76640: '2020-10-16',
  77288: '2020-10-09',
  77371: '2020-10-30',
  87259: '2020-11-06',
  91926: '2020-11-06',
  95279: '2020-09-04',
  104082: '2020-10-30',
  110999: '2020-11-13',
  111022: '2020-08-21',
  112969: '2020-10-23',
  115865: '2020-09-18',
  119142: '2020-10-02'},
 'actor_id': {1: 100000224549517,
  662: 100000168029563,
  1719: 100000168029563,
  5780: 100000151529577,
  8589: 100000151529577,
  14569: 100000224549517,
  15334: 100000151529577,
  19864: 100000151529577,
  21641: 100000224549517,
  24117: 100000168029563,
  33090: 100000168029563,
  38253: 100000151529577,
  44078: 100000168029563,
  53185: 100000168029563,
  56337: 100000151529577,
  59212: 100000168029563,
  63782: 100000151529577,
  64287: 100000151529577,
  65208: 100000168029563,
  65483: 100000151529577,
  66264: 100000151529577,
  70286: 100000224549517,
  76640: 100000224549517,
  77288: 100000168029563,
  77371: 100000224549517,
  87259: 100000168029563,
  91926: 100000151529577,
  95279: 100000224549517,
  104082: 100000168029563,
  110999: 100000224549517,
  111022: 100000168029563,
  112969: 100000224549517,
  115865: 100000224549517,
  119142: 100000224549517},
 'accuracy_score': {1: 0.894736842105263,
  662: 0.9523809523809521,
  1719: 0.904850746268656,
  5780: 0.877551020408163,
  8589: 0.7884615384615381,
  14569: 0.8571428571428571,
  15334: 0.972447325769854,
  19864: 0.8536585365853651,
  21641: 0.93717277486911,
  24117: 0.9,
  33090: 0.893617021276595,
  38253: 0.8444444444444441,
  44078: 1.0,
  53185: 0.9047619047619041,
  56337: 0.9189189189189191,
  59212: 0.957627118644067,
  63782: 0.9708737864077671,
  64287: 0.8690476190476191,
  65208: 0.8983050847457621,
  65483: 0.934537246049661,
  66264: 0.9487179487179481,
  70286: 0.86,
  76640: 0.855155482815057,
  77288: 0.9302325581395341,
  77371: 0.8785607196401791,
  87259: 0.875912408759124,
  91926: 0.8617021276595741,
  95279: 0.8,
  104082: 0.9822560202788341,
  110999: 1.0,
  111022: 0.6666666666666661,
  112969: 0.8824101068999021,
  115865: 0.8823529411764701,
  119142: 0.8478260869565211}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud pivot your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'week_end_date': {1: '2020-09-25',
  662: '2020-08-14',
  1719: '2020-10-16',
  5780: '2020-09-11',
  8589: '2020-09-18',
  14569: '2020-10-09',
  15334: '2020-10-30',
  19864: '2020-10-02',
  21641: '2020-11-06',
  24117: '2020-09-25',
  33090: '2020-10-02',
  38253: '2020-09-04',
  44078: '2020-09-11',
  53185: '2020-09-18',
  56337: '2020-10-09',
  59212: '2020-10-23',
  63782: '2020-11-13',
  64287: '2020-10-16',
  65208: '2020-11-13',
  65483: '2020-10-23',
  66264: '2020-09-25',
  70286: '2020-09-11',
  76640: '2020-10-16',
  77288: '2020-10-09',
  77371: '2020-10-30',
  87259: '2020-11-06',
  91926: '2020-11-06',
  95279: '2020-09-04',
  104082: '2020-10-30',
  110999: '2020-11-13',
  111022: '2020-08-21',
  112969: '2020-10-23',
  115865: '2020-09-18',
  119142: '2020-10-02'},
 'actor_id': {1: 100000224549517,
  662: 100000168029563,
  1719: 100000168029563,
  5780: 100000151529577,
  8589: 100000151529577,
  14569: 100000224549517,
  15334: 100000151529577,
  19864: 100000151529577,
  21641: 100000224549517,
  24117: 100000168029563,
  33090: 100000168029563,
  38253: 100000151529577,
  44078: 100000168029563,
  53185: 100000168029563,
  56337: 100000151529577,
  59212: 100000168029563,
  63782: 100000151529577,
  64287: 100000151529577,
  65208: 100000168029563,
  65483: 100000151529577,
  66264: 100000151529577,
  70286: 100000224549517,
  76640: 100000224549517,
  77288: 100000168029563,
  77371: 100000224549517,
  87259: 100000168029563,
  91926: 100000151529577,
  95279: 100000224549517,
  104082: 100000168029563,
  110999: 100000224549517,
  111022: 100000168029563,
  112969: 100000224549517,
  115865: 100000224549517,
  119142: 100000224549517},
 'accuracy_score': {1: 0.894736842105263,
  662: 0.9523809523809521,
  1719: 0.904850746268656,
  5780: 0.877551020408163,
  8589: 0.7884615384615381,
  14569: 0.8571428571428571,
  15334: 0.972447325769854,
  19864: 0.8536585365853651,
  21641: 0.93717277486911,
  24117: 0.9,
  33090: 0.893617021276595,
  38253: 0.8444444444444441,
  44078: 1.0,
  53185: 0.9047619047619041,
  56337: 0.9189189189189191,
  59212: 0.957627118644067,
  63782: 0.9708737864077671,
  64287: 0.8690476190476191,
  65208: 0.8983050847457621,
  65483: 0.934537246049661,
  66264: 0.9487179487179481,
  70286: 0.86,
  76640: 0.855155482815057,
  77288: 0.9302325581395341,
  77371: 0.8785607196401791,
  87259: 0.875912408759124,
  91926: 0.8617021276595741,
  95279: 0.8,
  104082: 0.9822560202788341,
  110999: 1.0,
  111022: 0.6666666666666661,
  112969: 0.8824101068999021,
  115865: 0.8823529411764701,
  119142: 0.8478260869565211}})

df.pivot(index="actor_id", columns=['week_end_date'])
```

Output:

```
                accuracy_score             ...                      
week_end_date       2020-08-14 2020-08-21  ... 2020-11-06 2020-11-13
actor_id                                   ...                      
100000151529577            NaN        NaN  ...   0.861702   0.970874
100000168029563       0.952381   0.666667  ...   0.875912   0.898305
100000224549517            NaN        NaN  ...   0.937173   1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Just to clarify, I added values to the pivot operator as such:

df.pivot(index="actor_id", columns='week_end_date', values='accuracy_score')